# installing developer tools in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have installed jdk1.7.0_17, then Eclipse Build id: 20100218-1602. I am trying to get the plug-in Android DDMS from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse and keep getting the same response. This is what I get  (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685)
  Missing requirement: Android Hierarchy Viewer 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685) requires 'org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2' but it could not be found.

Is this tool already installed or how do I resolve this issue?

Does anyone know how to help me get this

Answer (score 0):

You must download the adt first it's seems like you using eclipse so please select help->install new software then isntall the adt using this link https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ full guide avaible here ->http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Answer (score 0):

Your Eclipse version is too old. Build id 20100218-1602 is definitely before Eclipse 3.6.2, which is a minimum requirement for the ADT. You should really take the [all-in-one-bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) from the Android developer site, if you are not aware of these dependencies.